# CSS not styling html - I've tried everything

Tags: html, css

Recently my website (avocatheatre.com.au) was having caching issues so I removed all files from public_html on the server then re-uploaded my website. 
This fixed the caching problem but also stuffed up some CSS.

We run a theatre and have a sessions time page which runs a little bit of code that pulls the session times/day for viewing while deleting those running after the end of day.

It's embedded as a string of html code into the website (I run off Adobe Muse)

Somehow and I'm not sure why but the CSS styling has stopped working for this section of code and I've tried whatever I can think of to fix the issue including

1. changing the paths and also copying the style sheet to the root of site
2. Deleting and re-uploading that specific folder
3. Checking things like the htaaccess file & making sure the UTF matches up

Nothing's worked and I really need some help

See below for the string of code I embed into the website for the session times

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=‘/session_times_/session_times.css’>

  <div style="min-width: 920px; padding-top: none !important; margin-top: 
none !important; ">
    <?php
      $dateval = date('Ymd');
      include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/session_times_/sessions/' . $dateval . 
'_sessions.html');
    ?>
  </div>
   <div style="min-width: 920px;">
    <div style=" min-width: 920px; clear: both; text-align: center; padding: 
1em 0em .5em 0em;"><font color="white">Amazing films this week</font></div>
<?php
  $dateval = date('Ymd');
  include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/session_times_/days/' . $dateval . '_days.html');
?>
  </div>
```

Here's a direct link to the sessions time page ( I've placed an image above the code so scroll down) - http://avocabeachpicturetheatre.com.au/session-times.html

Here's a direct link to the CSS - http://avocabeachpicturetheatre.com.au/session_times_/session_times.css

Comment: Great job describing what you have tried but as a reader I have no idea what your question is and what you are trying to solve! What CSS has stopped working?

Comment: Your CSS file is not there. **(Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)** because you're using the wrong type of quotes. use *href="/session_times_/session_times.css"* instead

Comment: Your `href` has some rather strange quote marks in your `<link>` (`‘’`). Those aren't the same as single-quotes (`'`). Can you try replacing those for standard single-quotes (`''`) or double-quotes (`""`) and see if that fixes the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=‘/session_times_/session_times.css’>
```

Note that the `‘` characters aren't regular single quotes.

This line of code causes a 404 not found error:

[image]

Change that to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/session_times_/session_times.css'>
```

And your styles will apply.

Here's the faulty code, pay attention to the last line:

```
<body class="always_vert_scroll">

  <div class="museBGSize clearfix" id="page"><!-- group -->
   <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu155964"><!-- group -->
    <div class="clip_frame clearfix grpelem" id="u155964"><!-- image -->
     <img class="position_content" id="u155964_img" src="images/hedge-31036x187.png?crc=4203777109" alt="" width="1035" height="186"/>
    </div>
    <div class="rounded-corners clearfix grpelem" id="u391521"><!-- column -->
     <div class="position_content" id="u391521_position_content">
      <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U166637-BP_infinity" template="session-times.html" data-type="html" data-ice-options="disableImageResize,link,txtStyleTarget" -->
      <div class="Event-Titles-Blue--H1 clearfix colelem" id="u166637-7" data-muse-uid="U166637" data-muse-type="txt_frame" data-IBE-flags="txtStyleSrc"><!-- content -->
       <h1 id="u166637-2"><span id="u166637">SESSION TIMES</span></h1>
       <h1 id="u166637-4">- CLICK NAMES FOR MORE DETAILS -</h1>
       <h1 id="u166637-5">&nbsp;</h1>
      </div>
      <!-- /m_editable -->
      <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U611873-BP_infinity" template="session-times.html" data-type="image" -->
      <div class="clip_frame colelem" id="u611873" data-muse-uid="U611873" data-muse-type="img_frame"><!-- image -->
       <img class="block" id="u611873_img" src="images/screen%20shot%202017-07-07%20at%20123714%20pm.jpg?crc=4169811894" alt="" width="458" height="792" data-muse-src="images/screen%20shot%202017-07-07%20at%20123714%20pm.jpg?crc=4169811894"/>
      </div>
      <!-- /m_editable -->
      <div class="colelem" id="u611526"><!-- custom html -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=‘/session_times_/session_times.css’>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a 404 not found in your css style file. Check the external file path of that css carefully.

> http://avocabeachpicturetheatre.com.au/%E2%80%98/session_times_/session_times.css%E2%80%99
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)